# How to update a table with I need to fetch the data from multiple sub-queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 4 columns that is currently NULL, the table looks like:

```
Users
- userId
- wantsMail   YES or NO
```

For each of these 4 columns, I need to perform a query based on a row in another table (UserChoices) that looks like:

```
userId  questionId answer (BIT)
123     3929       1
```

Note: The answer is a BIT, so 1 has to be translated to 'YES', and 0 to 'NO'

So I have to go through all the rows in the User table, and then update the columns using the 'UsersChoices' table.  For each column, I have the questionId that I need to lookup.

So for 'wantsMail" the questionId would be e.g. 1039

What is the best way to go about a query like this?

Comment: There is no best way, if you have a way that works, use it.

Comment: Could you please show the query you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want - it will insert all rows from UserChoices where the questionId = 3929 while translating answer into wantsMail:

```
INSERT INTO Users (userId, wantsMail)
SELECT
    UserId
    , CASE answer
        WHEN 1 THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'NO'
      END AS wantsMail
FROM UserChoices
WHERE questionId = 3929
```

**UPDATE**: Adding Syntax for Updating existing values:

```
UPDATE Users AS U
SET U.wantsMail = CASE c.answer WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
FROM 
    Users AS U
    INNEr JOIN
    UserChoices AS C ON U.UserId = C.UserId
WHERE
    C.questionId = 3929
```

This, of course, is untested since I don't have your database.  But, should point you in the right direction for what you are trying to do.

Comment: It is an update statement, not an insert.  All the rows are in the table already, but the column needs to be updated.

Comment: crap - sorry about that - I assumed you wanted to insert into an empty table.  The syntax for the update will be different...stay tuned